# Why git help branch does not work with --no-pager?

Tags: git, terminal, zsh

I'm trying to display `git help branch` without less into zsh using `git --no-pager help branch`. But it's still opens in less with the `(END)`. So I have to close it every time `q` button and can not see the documentation while writing terminal commands.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue with Bash. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Same goes for `git --no-pager help checkout`
It does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git help` calls [`man`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/man) and `man` uses its own pager configuration, it knows nothing about and doesn't obey `git --no-pager`. To configure or disable a pager for `man` use environment variables `MANPAGER` (specific) or `PAGER` (generic). Example:

```
MANPAGER=cat git help branch
```

Comment: This should be documented in git-help. Not that it uses `man`, but that it does not honor `--no-pager`.

Comment: But - @Schwern (and phd) - sometimes `git help` doesn't run `man`, sometimes it fires up a web browser. It's a bit messy. The documentation should certainly be clearer one way or another though.

Comment: @torek `git help` can run GNU info viewer, man page viewer (not necessary `man`), or a web browser. But in all 3 cases it runs an external program and always ignores `git --no-pager`. See [`git help help`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help).